# Creating a new object of the class vs. Navigator in Flutter

Tags: flutter

As far as I know, there are two ways to go to another screen in Flutter:

1. Creating a new object of the class (e.g: new ShowRoute())
2. Navigating to the class (Navigator.push(context) ... )

What is the difference between them and in what condition we use 1st or 2nd one?

Comment: please add some what you tried and errors what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Navigator is more natural way of transitioning from one screen to another. This is platform agnostic as well and handles back navigation automatically. Meanwhile, if you're trying to show different views inside your build method, you'll be handling all this back navigation yourself which is definitely not a recommended approach.

Go easy on yourself and use Navigator :)

Comment: for example I have P1 and P2, where P1 is products list and P2 is product details, in my UI I want to show P2 as a card on the P1, where P1 is still there but blured and P2 is infront of it, if I use navigator it won't show P1 in the background while showing P2 infront of it, navigator will replace the P1 with P2, while creating the object of P2 only shows the P2 infront of the P1, while P1 is there but blured!
I hope you undertand what I want to say :)

Comment: Got it now, you can use a custom dialog in this case. Dialogs in Flutter are fully customizable. You can also use a modal bottom sheet which would show the detail of the item selected in P1.